# Passing an array as an argument to a function pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, arguments

I'm currently studying pointers to functions and have been practicing on sort array functions.
The point is I input a sequence of numbers into the function and the program will re arrange it in ascending order. It worked just fine when I do a call by value function (I think that's how you call it). However when I try to assign a pointer to function and try to use that pointer instead of the function itself, it returns a bunch of errors. I'm sure the problem is due to the fact that I'm passing an array as an argument to the function POINTER. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

void sort(int a[], int size);
void swap(int *elt1, int *elt2);
main()
{
    int i; int array[SIZE]= {1,9,3,2,4,100,43,23,32,12};
    void (*fptr)(int array, int SIZE);
    fptr = &sort;
    (*fptr)(array,SIZE);
    /*sort(array, SIZE);*/
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void sort(int a[], int size)
{
    int pass, j;
    for(pass = 0; pass<size;pass++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                    if(a[j]>a[j+1])
                    {
                            swap(&a[j], &a[j+1]);
                    }
            }

    }


}


void swap(int *elt1, int *elt2)
{
    int hold;
    hold = *elt1;
    *elt1 = *elt2;
    *elt2 = hold;

}
```

Comment: The types of `void (*fptr)(int array, int SIZE)` don't seem the same of `void sort(int a[], int size)`.

Comment: @Jack They may not *seem* to be the same, but they *are.*

Comment: @H2CO3 and `int` and a pointer to `int`? Actually I pointed out your same issue so I don't see your point.

Comment: @H2CO3 help the slow guy (me). When is an `int` synonymous with an `int*` (`intptr_t` not withstanding =P)

Comment: @H2CO3 had to qualify that, or I just *knew* you'd bring it to the table =P

Comment: @WhozCraig I certainly would have done so :P

Comment: @Jack You speak easily after having edited your comment. First you wrote that `void (*)(int[], int)` wasn't the same as `void (*)(int *, int)` which is **wrong.** Now you edited your comment, so it states that `void (*)(int, int)` isn't the same as `void (*)(int *, int)` which is **right.**

Comment: @H2CO3: No. I didn't edit my comment in such way. I copied and pasted code from the OP so you are just wrong. I guess you misread. The edit was just to include `void` return type inside the code block because it fell outside syntax. Do you think I would rewrite both signatures when I had them ready to be copied and pasted in the question?

Comment: @H2CO3: just for the sake of truth: http://img.im/i/re2vm8 ;)

Comment: Jack any suggestion son how to make it look the same as sort

Comment: @Jack OK, sorry. You're right.

Comment: @H2CO3: Don't worry. I was just a matter of principle, you know. I forgive you with a warm hug though.

Answer (score 7):

The first argument of the function is a pointer to `int` (that is, `int *`), and not `int`.

```
void (*fptr)(int array, int SIZE);
```

should be

```
void (*fptr)(int *array, int SIZE);
```

Comment: H2CO3, thanks but its still not working.. Here is what I get: sortpointeragain.c:9: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
sortpointeragain.c:10: error: ‘fptr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sortpointeragain.c:10: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
sortpointeragain.c:10: error: for each function it appears in.)

Comment: @user2059456: did you notice that your second parameter here: `void (*fptr)(int array, int SIZE)` has the same name of a `#define`? What happens is that preprocessor replaces it to `void (*fptr)(int array, int 10)` which is obviously not correct. Use a different name.

Comment: Yeah I tried to define SIZE to be 10 and use it as size of the array.. I'll try using another name.. get back to you in a second

Comment: Jack man you rock. You were right!!! But why can't I do such a thing.. I'm defining SIZE to be 10 which is an int and the pointer to function is expecting an int so it should be fine right???

Comment: OOOOHHH I see, the pointer is expecting a VARIABLE of type integer not just a number thrown in..... Am I right?

Comment: The difference is not the fact that the call expects a variable, you can easily pass literals as H2CO3 said. The problem here is that you are defining a signature, not calling a function.

Comment: @user2059456 I wouldn't say. You can call functions with literals.

Comment: Hey Jack I'm new to c programming, I just started a couple of weeks ago.. Is there anyway I can save you as favorite in case I have other questions please!!! you know this tiny thing caused me hours of frustration and took you only seconds to figure it out so your help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: And by the way, I need to practice on dynamic memory allocation.. Any useful resources you can refer me to... The textbook I'm working on has about half a page on the subject and doesn't offer any examples or practice problems